# UICollectionView vs UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I need to have different full screen views in my app. Very similar to how snapchat works. The views should be able to communicate between each other.

My question is: **Should I use a UICollectionView with cells same size as the screen or should I use UIPageViewController?**

Please provide some background info to support your opinion!

Comment: What kind of content do you have in this "screens"? If there are similar views then use collection view, if different controllers - page view controller

Answer (score -3, accepted):

UIPageViewController use different view controller and load multiple controller so obvisioly  take more memory as compared to UICollectionView. So if your required task is less calculation or step  to do then its recommended to use UICollectionView, other case preferred way is to user UIPageController.

Answer (score 4):

I think both have pretty different purposes. 
UICollectionView is great to build a mosaic of views (think an image gallery for instance), whereas UIPageViewController is kind of similar to the flipping pages of a book. The latter seems to be what you need, but UIPVC doesn't seem to offer many tweaking/customizations, like custom transitions for example. In which case you may want to start from a UIScrollView with paging enabled to recreate something similar but with more potential. Here's an [example](https://gist.github.com/simondec/57a1ad9ef02bb50def8b).

Answer (score 2):

Personal opinion: for this specific case I'd use a page view controller. Collection views have any things you have to consider, like when the device rotates you have to recalculate where you are, which cell you have to display, ask to scroll to the current cell, and if you are displaying a video or using the camera you might have to control it perfectly, otherwise issues will come.
However think about new features that might be added to your app, if you think you might show more than 2 items on screen, then you'd better choose a collection view.

Answer (score 0):

> A page view controller lets the user navigate between pages of
>   content, where each page is managed by its own view controller object.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/

So If you plan to swipe from one ViewController to another, go for PageViewController. If you plan to have only one ViewController that deal with a list of fullscreen image or so, go for a view controller with a collectionView, or maybe your own swipeView.